# Migrating from Redux to Redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm slowly migrating over from Redux to Redux toolkit. I'm still pretty new but I have this login action function. How can I translate old function below do I need `createAsyncThunk` to achieve this?

```
export const login = (email, password) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(requestLogin());
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((user) => {
      dispatch(responseLogin(user));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch(loginError());
    });
};
```

and my auth slice looks something like this:

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "authSlice",
  initialState: {
    isLoggingIn: false,
    isLoggingOut: false,
    isVerifying: false,
    loginError: false,
    logoutError: false,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: {},
  },
  reducers: {
    signInWithEmail: (state, action) => {
      const { email, password } = action.payload;
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((response) => {
          const {
            uid,
            email,
            emailVerified,
            phoneNumber,
            password,
            displayName,
            photoURL,
          } = response.user;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {},
});
```

Comment: You can use `createAsyncThunk` if you need to `dispatch` in your action creator. Can you use `async/await` in your project?

Comment: Yes, since mark already provided an answer. Are you able to show me how to dispatch my action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reducer you showed is very wrong. **Reducers must *never* do *anything* async!**

You don't *need* `createAsyncThunk`, but if you *want* to use it, it'd be like this:

```js
export const login = createAsyncThunk(
  'login',
  ({email, password}) => firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
);

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "authSlice",
  initialState: {
    isLoggingIn: false,
    isLoggingOut: false,
    isVerifying: false,
    loginError: false,
    logoutError: false,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: {},
  },
  reducers: {
    /* any other state updates here */
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(login.pending, (state, action) => {
      // mark something as loading here
    }

    builder.addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      // mark request as complete and save results
    }
  }
});
```

Note that `createAsyncThunk` only allows one argument to be passed to the thunk action creator, so it now must be an object with both fields instead of separate arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mark. Initially I had `[login.pending]: (state) => {}` in my reducers but that was not working. Does it need to be wrapped within Builder for all my asyncThunk?

Comment: You can use that syntax in `extraReducers` to respond to actions that were defined outside of the slice, but not inside `reducers.`  However, since that syntax doesn't work well with TypeScript, we're now encouraging use of the "builder" syntax as the preferred approach.

Comment: how to get a firebase reference?

Answer (score 2):

Lets create a `productSlice.js`

`import { createSlice,createSelector,PayloadAction,createAsyncThunk,} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";`

```
export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  "products/fetchProducts", async (_, thunkAPI) => {
     try {
        const response = await fetch(`url`); //where you want to fetch data
        return await response.json();
      } catch (error) {
         return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({ error: error.message });
      }
});

const productsSlice = createSlice({
   name: "products",
   initialState: {
      products: [],
      loading: "idle",
      error: "",
   },
   reducers: {},
   extraReducers: (builder) => {
      builder.addCase(fetchProducts.pending, (state) => {
        state. products = [];
          state.loading = "loading";
      });
      builder.addCase(
         fetchProducts.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
            state. products = payload;
            state.loading = "loaded";
      });
      builder.addCase(
        fetchProducts.rejected,(state, action) => {
            state.loading = "error";
            state.error = action.error.message;
      });
   }
});


export const selectProducts = createSelector(
  (state) => ({
     products: state.products,
     loading: state.products.loading,
  }), (state) =>  state
);
export default productsSlice;
```

In your `store.js` add `productsSlice: productsSlice.reducer` in out store reducer.

Then for using in component add those code ... I'm also prefer to use hook

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import { fetchProducts,selectProducts,} from "path/productSlice.js";
```

Then Last part calling those method inside your competent like this

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const { products } = useSelector(selectProducts);
React.useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(fetchProducts());
}, [dispatch]);
```

And Finally, you can access data as `products` in your component.